# A quizz show if the answer is correct or incorrect in the same page after submiting the answer not refresh

Tags: php, ajax

"I am working in a quizz I want it to let me know if the answer is correct or incorrect. My issue is that it does that but it tell me that is correct or not correct in the next page with the next question because it is refreshing the page everytime I submit the answer." I want it to tell the student if it is correct or incorrect in the same page before moving to the next page. 
If I eliminate the ajax It will display if the answer was correct or not correct but in the next page where the new question is displayed. All the codes are  in the same Php/html page. Thanks  in advance.

```
<?php while($row5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)): ;{ ?>
    <h1 align="center" ><?php echo $row5['Question'] ?></h1>
    <?php 
    $id = $row5['QuizzId'];
    $question = $row5['Question'];
    $correctAnswer=$row5['correctAnswer'];
    $ans_array = array($row5['notCorrect1'],$row5['notCorrect2'], $row5['correctAnswer']);
    shuffle($ans_array);
?>
    <label>A<input type="radio" value="<?php echo $ans_array[0]; ?>" name="name"> <?php echo $ans_array[0]; ?></label>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label>B<input type="radio" value="<?php echo $ans_array[1]; ?>" name="name"> <?php echo $ans_array[1]; ?></label>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label>C <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $ans_array[2]; ?>" name="name"> <?php echo $ans_array[2]; ?></label>
    <input type="hidden" name="correctAn" value="<?php echo $correctAnswer; ?>">
<?php } ?>
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="correct">
<script>
$('#correct').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'questions_1.php',
        data: 'correctAnswer1',
        success: function(php) {
            alert('yes');
        }               
    });
});
</script>
<?php
if($_GET["correctAnswer1"]){
    $mianswer = $_POST["name"];
    $correctAn = $_POST["correctAn"];
    if($mianswer==$correctAn) {
        echo "<h1>Great Job</h1>";
        echo '<br>';
        echo "<h1>The correct answer was $correctAn</h1>";
    } else {
        echo '<h1>Not correct</h1>';
        echo "<h1>The correct answer was $correctAn</h1>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Well, for starters, you can't have more than one name that is the same...

Comment: I forgot to mention that when I added the ajax function is not showing the correct or incorrect message at all.

Comment: @Sablefoste yes you can, they are radio buttons.

Comment: Why use ajax at all if you are passing the correct answer as a hidden field?

Answer (score 2):

First of all in your `ajax` request you have defined `type:'POST'` but you have used `$_GET` in php , change that i.e : `if($_POST['something'])`

Then you need to take value of `radio button` which is selected by user and `correct answer value`  .i.e:

```
 $("input[name='correct']").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    //getting selected radio button value
    var name=$("input[name='name']:checked").val();
   //getting value of correct answer
    var correctAn=$("input[name='correctAn']").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'questions_1.php',
             data: {'correctAn': correctAn,'name':name },//<-passing value to php
            success: function(php) {
                alert(php);
            }               
        });

    });
```

And in your `php script` , do like below :

```
if(isset($_POST['correctAn']) && isset($_POST['name'])){

   //getting values
        $mianswer=$_POST["name"];
        $correctAn=$_POST["correctAn"];
        //do something

}
```

Comment: The code is not working, when I click submit it is displaying the alert, with all the css, javascript and html source in the page.

Comment: I think the problem is in the success: function(php) but I have tried a few things like; changing it to html and adding a <div> to the php code but what it did was to insert another page with another question and displaying in it if the last answer was correct or not inside the previous question page.

Comment: @ElvisCruz I raised this question in the comments above. Why use ajax when you are passing the correct answer as a hidden field? The problem is in the php code: you don't have any logic to determine if the request is a regular request and you have to show the question form or it's an ajax request and have to show your message. Put the code at the start of the file inside an `else` block for `if (isset($_POST))...`

Comment: The problem is that is refreshing to a new page, I want it to show if the answer was correct or not in the same page

Comment: @ElvisCruz to do that you don't need an ajax call when you already have the correct answer in the page. Just prevent form submission. And you can't show html in an alert.

Comment: How do I prevent form submission if I need to get the correct answer and the student answer

Comment: @ElvisCruz See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing the correct answer as a hidden field there is no need to make an ajax call, you can manage what you want client-side. Is questionable if this is the right approach, since inspecting the page will reveal the correct answer, but based on what you are currently doing, this is a possibility.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); // This prevents form submission
    let answer = $("input[name='name']:checked").val();
    let correct = $("input[name='correctAn']").val();
    if (answer == correct) { // Check if selected option is the correct one
        alert('Congratulations!');
    }
});
```